# Read string containing double quotes and comma using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following JSON field with the following format:

```
"Classifications": ["Returning", "Important"]
```

My desired output would be the following string: `Returning, Important`

I am using the following syntax:

```
<string key="value">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(*[@key='Classifications'])"></xsl:value-of>
</string>
```

However, the output I get from this is: `ReturningImportant`

Appreciate your help in advance to use the right syntax to achieve my preferred output.

Comment: How does your XML representation of the JSON look (because your shown code seems to select from some XML)?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, indeed. I am first transforming the JSON to XML using `json-to-xml($input)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution for XSLT 1.0:

`normalize-space` implies a conversion of the nodeset `*[@key='Classifications']` to a string, and this conversion yields the concatenation of text nodes without any commas or spaces: `ReturningImportant`. This string is then unchanged by `normalize-space`.

You can implement a concatenation with commas and spaces as follows:

```xml
<string key="value">
  <xsl:for-each select="*[@key='Classifications']/*">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `select="*[@key='Classifications']/*" separator=", "/>`.

As for the newline you mention in the comment, I don't see that happening [with your input and my code](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%09xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%09exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%09version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22data%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22json-xml%22%20select%3D%22json-to-xml%28.%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22value%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24json-xml%2F*%2F*%5B%40key%3D%27Classifications%27%5D%2F*%22%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Cdata%3E%7B%22Classifications%22%3A%20%5B%22Returning%22%2C%20%22Important%22%5D%7D%3C%2Fdata%3E%0D%0A&input-type=XML) (slightly adapted to use the right context).

Comment: Thank you, it's almost perfect :)
I am getting the following output: `"Returning, VeryImportant\"\n`. What would you suggest to use to remove the new line at the end?

Comment: @ANN, with the posted input I don't see why my suggestion would insert any newline character.